# How to select IP and check if the time it was inserted is not less than 2min

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, time

1. I want to check if the time a message was inserted into a table is not less than 2min from the same IP address.
2. if time is not yet 2min from last insertion, echo how many minutes and seconds left before a user can come back and send a message from that very same IP.
3. I have a column 'mtime' (mysql, Type: datetime) which records the time a message was inserted into the table, so i hear my format must be in Unix, how do i convert to that in this process?

Here's my rough PHP.

```
   require_once '../php/db_conx.php';
if (!$con){
die(mysql_error());
}
  $ip = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ip = '$ip' AND mtime >= ' ".strtotime('2 minutes')."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      echo "You can only send 1 message every 2min.(eg $timeleft) before you can send your next message.."; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ip = '$ip' AND mtime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
```

to get seconds left

```
SELECT mtime - (now()- interval 2 minute) AS secondsLeft 
FROM messages 
WHERE ip = '$ip' AND mtime >= now() - interval 2 minute;
```

your php may look like something like this

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$con);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo "seconds Left: ".$row[0];
}
else
{
    //some code here to insert new record maybe
}
```

Comment: ok 1 and 3 are answered, i just don't understand what i must echo as time left from your above edit.

Comment: your `mysql_query` call is missing a connection

Comment: as others have suggested, you should look into using `mysqli_` methods

Comment: google for `php mysqli_query` `php mysqli_connect` and others

Comment: i am new to php too but it looks really simple to learn anyways